# Is there any python "utf-8" string constant?

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I would like to use "utf-8" string constant because it is always confusing for me to choose between "UTF-8", "UTF8", "utf8", "utf-8", "utf-8", "utf_8"

All code samples in python documentation have syntax like:

```
with io.open("/tmp/a.txt", "w", encode="utf-8") as file_cursor:
    file_cursor.write(text)
```

**Can somebody tell me why is like this, maybe some best practice, zends ... ?**

I would like to use code suggestion in IDE to achieve something like:

```
with io.open("/tmp/a.txt", "w", encode=ENCODINGS.UTF8) as file_cursor:
    file_cursor.write(text)
```

**Is there any standard constant out of the box in python core?**

Comment: Why does it matter? python accepts all of the above, you could even use `Utf - 8` or `- -uTf _#8_ - -` if you want. If you were to define constants for encodings, you'd probably end up with the names of the [standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) and their value equal to their names, which (at least to me) seems pointless and unpythonic, now you need to import those constants from somewhere before you can use them, and it doesn't add any value.

Comment: The advantage of using a constant is that it would be easier to spot even statically in case you make a mistake.

Answer (score 16):

You could use:

```
import encodings

encodings.utf_8.getregentry().name
```

which gives `'utf-8'`.

Comment: In Python 3.9.6 I get "Instance of 'CodecInfo' has no 'name' member" from `pylint` (presumably because `CodecInfo` is this bizarre `tuple` subclass with lots of properties. That seems to be a [false positive](https://github.com/linz/bde-processor-db-replica/pull/151).